# Css target element which does not contain the same element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I got the following html on page 1:

```
//Page 1:
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
    <junk>Welcome</junk>
</aside>
```

And the following on page 2:

```
//Page 2:
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
    <junk>
        <aside class="sidebar-light sidebar--medium"> //Whatever is in this should not change.
            <morejunk>Hello world!</morejunk>
        </aside>
    </junk>
</aside>
```

Junk are other div, classes, etc... Important is that all junks are not the same.

I can not change the HTML because I'm writing some CSS for a third-party web app. I can write some custom CSS for the entire application, not just for a single page. Now I want to target (change the color for example) of "Welcome". How can I do this without affecting "Hello world!"

The following CSS changes the color of both string, which I dont wan't.
   aside{
      color: yellow
   }

Comment: What do you mean by "target Welcome" ? You means target the first `aside` or target element without nested `aside` ?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: So you mean option 1 or option 2 ?

Comment: I mean option 2. I updated my question so I hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `>` selector like this:

```css
aside.sidebar > junk {
  color:red;
}

aside.sidebar > junk *,
aside.sidebar aside {
 color:initial;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
    <junk>Welcome</junk>
</aside>
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
    <junk>
        <aside class="sidebar-light sidebar--medium">
            <morejunk>Hello world!</morejunk>
        </aside>
    </junk>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```css
aside > div{
  color:red;
}
aside > div div{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
    <div>Welcome</div>
</aside>
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
    <div>
        <aside class="sidebar-light sidebar--medium">
            <div>Hello world!</morejunk>
        </aside>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `aside` does not change, you can use the pseudo-selector `:first-of-type` to select only the first `aside`:

```css
aside:first-of-type>junk {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
  <junk>Welcome</junk>
</aside>
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--medium">
  <junk>
    <aside class="sidebar-light sidebar--medium">
      <morejunk>Hello world!</morejunk>
    </aside>
  </junk>
</aside>
```

This way you don't have to worry about resetting the colour of the next `aside`.

Comment: The asides are not on the same page. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Ah. In that case you will need to do what the others are suggesting and target the second `aside` with its own `color` property.